# close and restart matlab ? or another way out?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, restart

I have a code that is quite computationally and memory-wise intensive and given the RAM(64Gb) I have, I can utilize it for my purpose and get my work done. My code does some kind of optimization, so I need to run my code again, but even after upon performing these operations

```
clear all;
close all;
pack;
```

I observe that MATLAB does not release the RAM fully, and only upon restarting, it does. I have some idea that this is a known problem with MATLAB, but I am just curious, has there been any new development that can help? I have R2017a running on Ubuntu16.04

Secondly, I am OK with re-starting and launching a new session, but running these commands

```
system('matlab &');
exit;
```

does not help. I see a startup screen, but there is no new window. Also, removing the '&' from above launches a new window but the previous one remains and the RAM is not freed.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Weird. How are you measuring the memory used? `clear all` should definitely suffice. Are you saying that if you run your code several times MATLAB will take more and more memory? Else, even if MATLAB is using a bit more memory than when it started, it will dump its stored garbage when new memory is needed

Comment: On windows I can do that by `system('matlab &'); exit;`. If you don't use `&` it will not continue with the current session, so the `exit` will not get called, and probably the RAM will not free. But what exactly happen with the new session? you see startup but it stuck? or just disappeared without new window?

Comment: I manage to do that without `&`, by call the `matlab.exe` directly instead of `matlab` as a shortcut. Try if that works for you- `system(['"' fullfile(matlabroot,'bin\matlab.exe') '"']); exit`

Comment: Hello @AnderBiguri, I am checking the RAM consumption by using the `htop` command on a linux terminal. `clear all` does release some memory, but not completely. Only after restarting the session, I see a very significant reduction. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Adiel, if I am not wrong, you seemed to have suggested it for Windows. I am working on Ubuntu16.04 where I found it to be not working. Could you think of a way out there? Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't have experience with that, sorry. Look at the "Tips" section in `system` documentation, there is a note about UNIX implementation  of the command, maybe it will help...

Comment: From what I understand `clear` marks the memory location as unused.  It is up to the OS to reclaim the space.  It could be Ubuntu is not reclaiming so it "appears" as being used by Matlab when running top.  However, Matlab might not really be using this memory after the clear.  What happens if you run your process, clear everything, & then run the same process again?  Does the memory usage continue to grow with each iteration?  If it keeps getting bigger then it sounds like a memory leak.  If not then it is probably just the OS not reclaiming the space until it is needed and no real issue

Comment: I believe that MATLAB uses its own memory management. When you create a large array that doesn't fit in MATLAB's pool, the pool increases. When you clear the array, the memory is added back to the available memory in the pool, but not released back to the system. So what you see is how much memory MATLAB has requested from the system, not the memory actually filled with data (or lost). If you see memory use increase consistently when running the same process over and over, that is when there's a memory leak. Otherwise, don't worry about what `top` says.

Comment: Dear @AeroEngy, I have some snapshots of the behavior here [link](https://imgur.com/a/HnTrY). From the snapshots, I can see that the RAM consumption increases in the next round, but gets released back to the previous state after clearing the workspace (although this does not seem to happen in the first round). Do you think it is the same memory leak issue you have mentioned? And is there a way to control it?

Comment: From just those 2 rounds of testing in your link I would not say there was a  a  leak.  Since after Round 1/clear & after Round 2/clear it looks like you were at approximately the same memory level.  If After Round 3,4,5 & clear it was steadily increasing then you could say there was a memory leak in something you were doing.   So if you want to be sure do more rounds of testing.